# html5 canvas game on mobilesafari darkening on tap

Tags: html, canvas, mobile-safari

i am developing a html5-canvas game which runs fine on most browsers, even mobile.

though on safari mobile if you tap on the canvas, it gets slightly darker - like if you tap on any html element. i guess this is for selection purposes.

is there any way to disable this darkening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS rule you can use: `-webkit-user-select: none;`.

Comment: thanks! this works perfectly in the normal safari mobile browser. however when i add a bookmark to the homescreen it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're seeing is indeed the selection of the canvas object. You could try hiding the highlight colour by setting the alpha to 0.

`* {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}`